# Flat buttons vs raised buttons

Tags: android, material-design

I want to know the basic difference between `Flat button` and `Raised Button`. According to the new `Android` material design guidelines i want to use raised button but i don't know what are they. there are forums on the web that display a button which is raised but they call it Flat.

can any one tell me the base difference between the two ? (By Look specifically)

Comment: You want to know the difference in the usage or the implementation ?

Comment: Just want to see the difference in the look

Comment: I am confused between FAB, FLAT and RAISED

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both `Button`s are following the new *Flat Design* concept instead of the old *Gradient Design* concept.

Those concept used to give the user the feeling of this is a **Clickable** button not just a colored area with text or image.

## Raised button

This is the `Raised Button` that gives you the feeling that it is relatively above the surface on part of it. Which give the user the feeling that he/she can push it down expecting a specific action. **More Elegant and give better UX**

[image: Raised button]

### Example

[image: Raised button example]

## Flat button

This is the `Flat Button`. Which is only depend on change part of the surface color to give the user the feeling of this is a different place that might give you different action if you clicked on it.

[image: Flat button]

### Example

[image: Flat button example]

## FAB button

This is the `FAB Button`. (FAB stands for `Floating Action Button`) Which is following the same concept of the `Raised Button` in Material Design, but with a floating feature. This FAB button can be used to indicate a primary action in an app.

[image: FAB Button]

### Example

### [image: FAB Button example]

## Choosing the type of button to use

> Choosing a button style depends on the primacy of the button, the number of containers on screen, and the screen layout. - [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types)

According to the [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types), you can choose which type of button to use based on these 3 factors:

> - **Function**: Is it important and ubiquitous enough to be a floating action button?
> - **Dimension**: Choose raised or flat depending on the container it will be in and how many z-space layers you have on screen. There should not be many layers of objects on the screen.
> - **Layout**: Use primarily one type of button per container. Only mix button types when you have a good reason to, such as emphasizing an important function.
>   [image: Choosing the button type to use - Pyramid]

### Possible usages

- Dialogs -> flat buttons
- Inline -> flat/raised buttons
- Always available -> FAB button/[persistent footer button](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-persistent-footer-buttons)

Comment: Thanks @Sami El-Tamawy +1. Marking as right. Can you please tell me how can i achive the raised button in android <=2.3 ?? Without using any third party library. .

Comment: @UsmanRiaz This is different question. You need to post it. Personally, I don't recommend that because each Android OS version have it's design concept and the flat design started with the ` KitKat` version. You don't need to do that. The <=2.3 user might feel this strange thing.

Comment: So what's the difference between `FAB button`, `RaisedButton` and `ElevatedButton` then ? they all look so similar

Answer (score 0):

Both have same functionality but the appearance is only the difference. It is more appealing to use raised button instead of a normal one. We can set that property in xml as `android:elevation="8dp"`. And the button is called Fab not Flat.

Comment: But there is no property like elevation in older versions. 2.3 and later less then 3

Comment: As of now there is no support to older versions for Fab and also ripple effect and many other Android L features

Comment: Isn't raised buttons are suggested?? Why Fab? Can you please describe the look of Fab and Raised button? not much of the detail but a little

Comment: Fab are used only for appearance. Messenger app for Android has Fab where we can compose a new message jst by clicking + icon it is easy and it stays floating without much confusion for the user refer - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en

Comment: @UsmanRiaz there are pretty good backports supporting elevation and ripples. https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon https://github.com/rey5137/material