# Remove the drop shadow from a RaisedButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to completely remove the drop shadow under the `RaisedButton`? I've set
`elevation: 0` to that very `RaisedButton` but the drop shadow still appears when tapping it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`RaisedButton` has four different `elevation` parameters. Just set them all to 0.

```dart
elevation: 0,
hoverElevation: 0,
focusElevation: 0,
highlightElevation: 0,
```

Comment: I was just gonna write this answer.

Comment: diabledElevation also or you can use a [FlatButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532812/flat-buttons-vs-raised-buttons)

Comment: Yeah @Ninja, that's true. I went on with a RaisedButton because of the ease of setting a background color but I could also use a `FlatButton` and set a background. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 26):

Since raised button is deprecated.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
               
                ),),
```

This should be the solution. It will remove the elevation and the shadows.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I understand your point but what should be deprecated should be the whole question... I mean, if someone wants to remove the elevation of a `RaisedButton` because they use an old version of Flutter or something like that, the accepted answer does the job, while yours doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 5):

Since the RaisedButton is deprecated and ElevatedButton should be used insted, the solution for this problem is also simple.

```
elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0)
```

Comment: elevation only expects type of double?

Comment: What do you mean? 0 is the same as 0.0. And yes elevation expects only type of double. Refer to the official documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/elevation.html

Answer (score 5):

You can find the answer here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html

You have to use:

```js
.copyWith(elevation:ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull(0.0))


//Example

ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Your Text"),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
          foregroundColor: Colors.black54,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ).copyWith(elevation:ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull(0.0))
```